# Angular route parameters return empty

Tags: angular, routes

I am copy and pasting the most basic examples I can find to try to get a minimal functioning piece of code but try as I might these Angular parameters return empty. I've added a couple of print statements at different places in an attempt to figure out if I'm just looking in the wrong place. I pulled this particular iteration from: https://www.kevinleary.net/angular-component-url-parameters/. I'm using `http://localhost:4200/char/thing` as my test URL.

Am I missing something obvious? I just can't figure out why this is still empty.

### app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'Character Search';

  // Dynamic parameters for this component's route: /example-params/:first/:second
  routeParams: Params;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
      this.getRouteParams();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log(id)
    console.log(this.routeParams);
  }

  // Store parameter values on URL changes
  getRouteParams() {
    // Route parameters
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe( params => {
        this.routeParams = params;
        console.log(params)
    });
  }
}
```

### Routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'

  
const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: 'char/:id',
      component: AppComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `snapshot` property of `ActivatedRoute` class. In addition to this, you must have to use the `router-outlet`

```
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

```html
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute        
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // First get the id from the current route.
    const routeParams = this.route.snapshot.paramMap;
    const idFromRoute = routeParams.get('id');
  
  }
```

Please find the code example here [Routing Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jpeujr?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: As seen in the above code - I am trying to use the snapshot property. Are you saying that those print statements will not work as expected?

Comment: Yes it will print the parameters value, did you tried?

Comment: I did - I'm sure I'm missing something and this isn't a reflection on your answer but I *think* I'm doing exactly what you're saying and I still get an empty parameter back. I also tried `const routeParams = this.routeParams.snapshot.paramMap;` as you indicated but the problem is that parameter map is empty as well. I inspected the object in the debugger and it has nothing listed.

Comment: Added a code example in Stackbliz..please check. Thanks!

Comment: So this seems to work but only if I click on the link. If I do something like brows to the url localhost:4200/hello/test it doesn't work. Is this not the same thing as clicking the link?

Comment: if you copy-paste the link https://angular-ivy-jpeujr.stackblitz.io/hello/test in the browser, it should work.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this. Working on it off and on. I downloaded your project and just ran it 100% as is and while navigating directly with URL works on stackblitz, the same project, run identically locally, doesn't work. I can click the link and it will navigate but if I navigate directly by URL it doesn't work. I've seen some posts as to why this is but I haven't figured out how to implement any of the answers